# How to create Database in couchdb

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I want to create a database in CouchDB using node.js as backend. I have an admin at my DBMS. I guess first we have to login and provide credential then create DB. I have tried some code (see below) but no luck. Can someone help me out?

Below is my code:

```
var request = require('request');

request.get(
    'http://127.0.0.1:5984/',
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var couchConnectionObject = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log('You are running couch DB version' + couchConnectionObject.version)
        }
    }
);

request.get(
    'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session',
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var couchConnectionObject = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(couchConnectionObject);
        }
        else{
            console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------');
            console.log('response :' + JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------');
            console.log('body :' + JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    }
);



request.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session',
     {
        'user': 'username',
        'pass': 'password',
        'sendImmediately': false
      },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------');
            var couchConnectionObject = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(couchConnectionObject);
        }
        else{
            console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------');
            console.log('response :' + JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------');
            console.log('body :' + JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited your post to improve formatting, it's actually easy to move the whole code into a `pre` block, just select it and press `ctrl+k`. Now, "no luck" is not a specific description of a problem. Please describe the expected and the actual behaviour of your code – this way it will be much easier to help you. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Not a CouchDB expert, but [this](https://medium.com/yld-engineering-blog/node-js-databases-using-couchdb-5135f6f45dc1) article might help you out. 
Also, have you tried to `npm install nano` (more info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#nanodbcreatename-callback))?

This simple line of code creates the database, according to the official doc

```
var nano = require('nano');
nano.db.create('alice').then((body) => {
  console.log('database alice created!');
})
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

If you just want to make it the raw way it should be

```
request.put('http://127.0.0.1:5984/[DBNAME]', <your callback here>);
```

Comment: Yeah I highly recommend to use nano which is the offical CouchDB NodeJS client

Comment: Thanks guys for your help but I wanted to know the internals so just doing this stuff raw. Can you guys help me out in doing it raw, without any other package

Comment: @Maddy I don't see why you should harm yourself so much if there is such a simple library. If you, anyways, want to pursuit your route, just make a PUT request with the following http://[ip of the server]:[port]/[db name]

Comment: @gianmarco my db has an admin so it asks for Authorization... My problem is to what key for user should I give and password if it's designed so... Or will couchdb prompt for password ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = require('request');    
request.put(
        {url : 'http://admin:ouchcouch@127.0.0.1:5984/newdb1'}, function(err,httpResponse,body) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('Error:', err);
              }
              console.log('Body : ', body);
        }
    );
```

I used this code to authenticate and create a new DB in Couch Database

Comment: this link is also quite helpful... https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Complete_HTTP_API_Reference